# Difference bewteen using TableRowSorter with getColumnClass and without getColumnClass

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I sorted data a table in java.
Both sort with getColumnClass and without getColumnClass is done.
What's the difference between them?
Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

The `getColumnClass()` method is *required* for all implementations of `TableModel`; a table *without* `getColumnClass()` is *not* possible. It "is used by the `JTable` to set up a default renderer and editor for the column," as may be required to refresh rows changed due to sorting. The number of times it is called is unspecified.

If you suspect that your implementation is a problem, you should [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) the application.